# Pdo Exception (Mysql) no me detecta errores personalizados

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un mantenimiento en PHP (PDO) a una tabla mediante un Store Procedure (Mysql)  en una determinada situación lanzo una excepción desde el Mysql de la siguiente Manera:

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT='Cheque cobrado, no se puede anular.';
```

en PHP ejecuto la sentencia de esta forma:

```
try {
    ....................
    ....................
    ....................       
    $stmt->execute();
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error en la Ejecucion: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
```

Cabe recalcar que seteada la conexión con el atributo PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE-> PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION y me captura los errores usuales de MYSQL pero con los errores personalizados no he tenido suerte.

ya he probado en consola y desde VB.net y el procedimiento si devuelve el mensaje de error.

Comment: Pregunta: el problema es que no entra en el bloque catch o sí entra pero no muestra el mensaje de error?

Comment: No entra al bloque catch, es como si no hubiera error. el procedimiento almacenado funciona bien, pues no hace ninguna operación en la BD. pero el PHP no me coge el error.

Comment: Es posible que tengas que crear un stored procedure que te levante el error. De manera que en vez de llamar directamente a `SIGNAL...`  apliques algo como `CALL levantar_error(45000,'Cheque cobrado')`

Comment: Te puede interesar [este artículo](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/mysql/using-the-signal-statement-for-error-handling/) que trata sobre algo parecido a lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: El artículo que recomienda @A.Cedano arroja luz sobre la necesidad de emitir `SIGNAL` dentro de un bloque `BEGIN...END`, aunque pareciera estar escrito para MySQL 5.1. La versión actual es más expedita para esos errores personalizados

Comment: Acabo de leer el articulo me aclaro algunas dudas lamentablemente el ejemplo no esta en PDO, sin embargo acabo de darme cuenta que cuando lanzo la excepción desde un trigger el PDO si lo detecta debe ser por la naturaleza del trigger, el procedimiento parece que solo lo considera un Warnig, de todas maneras gracias Cedano y Amenadiel. (como cierro la pregunta)

Comment: @Emersoft en vez de cerrarla la puedes eliminar si lo ves conveniente.